# Child wants bathroom during parent's Amidah

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, minor-katan-child, bathroom

Are there any halachic guidelines when a child tells the parent that he wants to go to bathroom during the Amidah?

This occurred to me multiple times, with my 4-year-old who can use the bathroom alone (although cannot yet wipe for himself). Part of the problem that during the way there is a heavy door which he cannot open alone.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/113917/31534

Comment: I asked my rav and waiting for the answer. In the meantime, I've found that Piskei Teshuvah 104:1 mentions and allows this case, without quoting any sources or explanation.

Comment: Allows what  exactly? Your question doesn't actually specify anything specific

Comment: It lists among those examples for which are permitted to interrupt with halicha. https://ibb.co/zHg8j8K

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid the Shulchan Arukh does not allow it, except by shortening the prayer as follows:

> One must not interrupt the Amidah. Even if a Jewish king greets him he should not answer. However, with a non-Jewish king, if it is possible to complete the prayer by shortening it before the king reaches him, one should do so, by saying the beginning and ending of each remaining blessing. Or, if it is possible to move to the side of the road and thereby avoid having to interrupt one’s prayer, one should do so. In any case, one should avoid speaking during one’s prayer, but if that is impossible one should interrupt by speaking. [SA, OC 104:1]

Comment: Thank you! But my case never really involves speaking, my son understands completely that I am not allowed to talk then. It is just about going away and returning. Which might be somewhat similar to moving to the side in your quotation?

Comment: I would interpret it that way, yes.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi sorry Dr. but it appears you got the wrong quote (that's the SH). MB 104:1 doesn't say this. It might even be permitting OP's case. Please double check and rewrite and I'll give you your upvote back :) https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.104.1

Comment: You are right, I had the SH, but MB 104:1 does not add to it:  "In the case of a crying child, it is permissible to gesture to him with his hands so that the child will quiet down and not disturb one’s prayer."

Comment: What about MB 104:10? @Binyomin would gesturing or moving location be of use as answers to your question?

Comment: Gesturing definitely doesn't help. He needs me accompanying him, and this might be defined as moving location. I don't know if it is an issue that I go to a place where I would be technically unable to say words of kedusha (and I subsequently wash hands afterwards)?

Comment: Also, does it make a difference if it might last longer than finishing Shemoneh Esreh?

Comment: @Binyomin I think you need to CYLOR

Comment: Think about it this way, if you don't take him, it may well be prohibited for you to continue praying anyway...

Comment: This answer requires deducing the halacha via one's own logic and does not present any sources that actually back the position opined.